# Epiceditor paired with MathJax

Tags: javascript, mathjax, epiceditor

Is there anyway to load a script (such as MathJax) into the EpicEditor preview iFrame? I want my previews to be correct Markdown and then have the javascript run to preview the MathJax content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you ought to inject MathJax script manually into previewer iframe. Something like this:

```
var editor = new EpicEditor(opts).load();

previewer = editor.getElement('previewer');
var mathjax = previewer.createElement('script');
mathjax.type = 'text/javascript';
mathjax.src = 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML';
previewer.body.appendChild(mathjax);

var config = previewer.createElement('script');
config.type = 'text/x-mathjax-config';
config.text = "MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$']], displayMath: [['$$','$$']], processEscapes: true}});";
previewer.body.appendChild(config);
```

And then you can render equations on preview event:

```
editor.on('preview', function() {
    editor.getElement('previewerIframe').contentWindow.eval(
        'MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);');
});
```

That also works in fullscreen live edit mode.

Comment: If you take this approach, is there a mechanism to resize the preview iframe after the content changes height?  The reflow method resizes the iframe based on the container, which is no good.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).